# Draw line on map when button is clicked (using Google Maps API 3, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, button, google-maps-api-3, drawing, line

I am using Google Maps API 3. I have a map and a button. On the map, I have two markers. When I click the button, I want to draw a line between the two markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need Ajax.  With 2 markers and the google maps API v3 you can draw a straight line between them.

something like this (run when the button is clicked) should work with the correct names of marker1 and marker2:

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({path:[marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()});
```

Tested in IE on this [map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html)

with this in the address bar:

```
javascript:{var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({path:[gmarkers[0].getPosition(), gmarkers[1].getPosition()], map:map});}
```